# How can I quickly sum all numbers in a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

Each line contains text and numbers in one column. I need to calculate the sum of the numbers in each row. How can I do that? Thx

example.log contains:

```
time=31sec
time=192sec
time=18sec
time=543sec
```

The answer should be **784**

Comment: I tried this method awk '{ sum += $1}; END { print sum }' example.log but it's only for numbers in line

Comment: There is almost the same question in [SO]: [How can I quickly sum all numbers in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2702564/). Maybe time to have cross-site duplicates?

Answer (score 18):

If your `grep` support `-o` option, you can try:

```
$ grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' file | paste -sd+ - | bc
784
```

POSIXly:

```
$ printf %d\\n "$(( $(tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' <file | paste -sd+ -) ))"
784
```

Answer (score 16):

With a newer version (4.x) of GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="[0-9]+"}{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

With other `awk`s try:

```
awk -F '[a-z=]*' '{s+=$2}END{print s}'
```

Comment: You need `s+0` in case where `s` is empty, it will print `0` instead of empty.

Comment: Let me explain that. - There is just one case where `s` can be empty; if the input data contains **no lines** (i.e. if there is **no input at all**). In that case there are two behaviours possible; 1) no input => no output, or 2) always output something, if only 0. Both are sensible options depending on the application context. The `+0` is addressing option 2). To address option 1) you'd rather have to write `END {if(s) print s}`. - Therefore it makes no sense to assume either option (for this corner case of no data) until it is specified by the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
awk -F= '{sum+=$2};END{print sum}'
```

Comment: We prefer long form answers. Can you please elaborate on how this works?

Comment: @slm, that answer is not any more or less verbose than the other answers here and is self explanatory. It also has the advantage of working with input like `time=1.4e5sec`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - agreed, but this is a new user and we do encourage users to provide more than single line answers. A bit of text explaining how it works would make it a much stronger answer than just code.

Comment: @slm, this is a new user with one of the best answers (from a technical stand point) and he gets two downvotes and a negative comment. Not a very warm welcome.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I notice you made a slight rearrangement to the code. Any reason that the `;` needs to be in there at all? Shouldn't it just be removed entirely?

Comment: @TomFenech, the POSIX syntax for awk requires that those pattern/action items be separated by either ";" or "newline", so you may find awk implementations where it fails without this ";".

Comment: @slm You want me to rewrite the manual?

Comment: @snth - certainly not. But a short description of what code does is always the approach one should aim for when writing an answer. Someone that is providing guidance in the form of an answer should always take it as a teaching moment for the person asking the Q as well as anyone else that might find their answer when they search via Google in the future. Writing answers is voluntary and I don't think it's too much to ask for a sentence or two to go along with code.

Comment: @slm depends on how much free time you have and how you value it, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Another GNU `awk` one:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+' '{n+=RT};END{print n}'
```

A `perl` one:

```
perl -lne'$n+=$_ for/\d+/g}{print$n'
```

A POSIX one:

```
tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' | grep . | paste -sd + - | bc
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sed 's/=/ /' file | awk '{ sum+=$2 } END { print sum}'
```

Comment: Awesome answer, but no need for `sed`: `awk --field-separator = '{ sum+=$2 } END { print sum}' data.dat`

Comment: @user1717828: you should rather use the (shorter, and more compatible!) `-F'='` instead of `--field-separator =`

Comment: @OlivierDulac, weird, my `man awk` only gives `-F fs` and `--field-separator fs`

Comment: @user1717828: `-F'='` or `-F '='` are 2 ways of doing the `-F fs` (fs is "=" in your case) . I added the singlequotes to ensure the fs is properly seen & interpreted by awk, not the shell (usefull if the fs is ';' for example)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
awk -F"[^0-9]+" '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum+0; }' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Everyone has posted awesome `awk` answers, which I like very much.

A variation to @cuonglm replacing `grep` with `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' example.log | paste -sd'+' - | bc
```

1. The `sed` strips everything except for the numbers.
2. The `paste -sd+ -` command joins all the lines together as a single line
3. The `bc` evaluates the expression

Answer (score 3):

Through python3,

```
import re
with open(file) as f:
    m = f.read()
    l = re.findall(r'\d+', m)
    print(sum(map(int, l)))
```

Comment: `re.findall` returns a list of strings, this is not going to work

Comment: @1_CR ya , I forget that. Check it now.

Comment: Maybe `sum(int(e) for e in l)` is more pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a calculator.

```
{ tr = \ | xargs printf '[%s=]P%d+p' | dc; } <infile 2>/dev/null
```

With your four lines that prints:

```
time=31
time=223
time=241
time=784
```

And more simply:

```
tr times=c '    + p' <infile |dc
```

...which prints...

```
31
223
241
784
```

If speed is what you're after then `dc` is what you want. Traditionally it was `bc`'s compiler - and still is for many systems.

Comment: Not according to [my measurements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382280/7552): it depends how much work you have to do to generate the formula

Comment: @glennjackman - your measurements don't include `dc` as near as I can tell. What are you talking about?

Comment: By the way, when comparing the old crew to the new crew - such as when you benchmark `perl` v the standard unix toolset - it really doesn't make much sense if you use GNU tools compiled on a GNU toolchain. All of the bloat that can negatively affect Perl's performance is *also* in *all* of those GNU-compiled GNU utils. Sad but true. You need a real, simply built, simple toolset to accurately judge the difference. Like an heirloom-toolchest set statically linked against musl libs for instance - in that way you can bench the one-tool/one-job paradigm vs the one-tool-to-rule-them-all one.

Answer (score 3):

**Pure bash solution (Bash 3+):**

```
while IFS= read -r line; do                   # While it reads a line:
    if [[ "$line" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then      # If the line contains numbers:
        ((counter+=BASH_REMATCH[0]))          # Add the current number to counter
    fi                                    # End if.
done                                  # End loop.

echo "Total number: $counter"         # Print the number.
unset counter                         # Reset counter to 0.
```

---

**Short version:**

```
while IFS= read -r l; do [[ "$l" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && ((c+=BASH_REMATCH)); done; echo $c; c=0
```

Comment: Maybe also: `PS4='$((x+=${time%s*}))' time=0 x=0 sh -x <infile`